# Input mask - I want to convert to upper case AND apply regex at the same time

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

I am using the jquery.inputmask library.
For a UK National Insurance Number the following REGEX applies:

> ^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-DFM]{0,1}$

See http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=527&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

However what I would like would be for the user when he enters the number to have his letters transformed to uppercasing.
But when I include these lines of code in jquery, I cannot enter anything;

```
var regexNationalInsuranceNumber = "^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-DFM]{0,1}$";
$("input.niNo").inputmask("AA999999A").inputmask("Regex", { regex: regexNationalInsuranceNumber });
```

So how do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, you'll need to add casing: 'upper'

```
$("input.niNo").inputmask("AA999999A").inputmask("Regex", { 
   regex: regexNationalInsuranceNumber,
   casing: 'upper' });
```

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#casing

---

However, I cannot get that to work correctly, so I went with a css route instead:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Answer (score 1):

Teste this!

```
$('.maskAndUppercase')
.keyup(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().toUpperCase());
})
.mask('AAA-0AA0', {
    selectOnFocus: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a .toUpperCase() method:

```
var regexNationalInsuranceNumber = "^[A-CEGHJ-PR-TW-Z]{1}[A-CEGHJ-NPR-TW-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[A-DFM]{0,1}$";
$("input.niNo")
  .val($("input.niNo").val().toUpperCase())
  .inputmask("AA999999A")
  .inputmask("Regex", { regex: regexNationalInsuranceNumber });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase